# Is there is any way to export only new data from sql to oracle? useing ssis

Tags: mysql, oracle, ssis, etl

Hi i am new is sql ssis n trying to export data from sql to oracle which is working fine but every time it Exports all the data which is very time consuming .Is there is any way to export only new data from sql to oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend entirely on your data and whether or not your can identify which data rows are new or updated.  The best way to do this is to have a last modified date or a version number for each row that is updated each time the row is changed in any way.  If you have this you can then simply look for the maximum last modified data in your Oracle table and export everything more recent from your source table.

If you don't have this, generally you pull all the data into a staging environment, do a lookup on the key fields to see which rows are missing from your target database and then load only those into your target table.

If you have no way of identifying new rows entirely within your source table, you will need to transfer everything across to do a comparison via SSIS.

Comment: i cant change tables structure in SQL As i m not authorized for it.i am  thinking to create a windows service which will pull the last half n hour data from SQL an transfer to oracle.will it be valid for this?

Comment: @ashishjayara  How are you going to identify "the last half hour" of data?  If you will be doing this using data in the source system you should just use that in your SSIS packages.  What is your windows service going to be doing?

Comment: ya i got it making lookup based on record identification works.thanks